# Count of Distinct users based on dynamic dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that records the date each time a user logs in to my application.

the table looks like this:

```
Userid: int
logintime: timestamp
```

the data looks like this:

```
Userid   logindate
2        2013-09-01
2        2013-09-02
3        2013-09-02
4        2013-09-02
4        2013-09-03
5        2013-09-03
```

I want to find the number of distinct users that are new every day while keeping track of old users so the results I want looks like this:

```
logindate   count of users
2013-09-01  1
2013-09-02  3 
2013-09-03  4
```

On 2013-09-01 I need to count distinct on this day
On 2013-09-02 I need to count distinct between 2013-09-01 and 2013-09-02
On 2013-09-03 I need to count distinct between 2013-09-01 and 2013-09-03

I thought of something like the below but it never returns (takes alot of time)

```
select date(ul.logintime) d, 
(select count(distinct ul2.userid) from userlogin ul2 where 
date(ul2.logintime) between ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1) 
and date(ul.logintime)) dis from userlogin ul where month(logintime) = 9;
```

I am using Mysql server, any help

Comment: It seems you meant `2` instead of `4` in count of users from date `2013-09-03`

Comment: no i meant 4, that is my problem, I need to count recursively every day, for example: on 2013-09-02 i need to count distinct between 2013-09-01 and 2013-09-02. on 2013-09-03 i need to count distinct between 2013-09-01 and 2013-09-03.

Comment: Oh ok. So the unique values from the oldest date up to the current logindate. I've added a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select 
* 
from 
myTable
GROUP BY
DATE(logintime), userId
```

Comment: I can't figure out why this query works. can you please elaborate?

Comment: @alyrafea Actually I am grouping on the DATE, which I am extracting from the datetime column

Comment: I need to count recursively every day, for example: on 2013-09-02 i need to count distinct between 2013-09-01 and 2013-09-02. on 2013-09-03 i need to count distinct between 2013-09-01 and 2013-09-03.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this might work:

```
SELECT
  date(greatest(t1.logindate, t2.logindate)) ld,
  count(DISTINCT t2.userid) amount
FROM t t1
JOIN t t2 ON t1.logindate >= t2.logindate
GROUP BY ld
ORDER BY ld
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c89a7/1).

Comment: thanks for the suggested solution, I guess we are quite there, but unfortunately this query takes forever to run, and suggestions to how to make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT (distinct Userid),logindate
FROM Userlogin
Group by Logindate
```

Comment: This is doesn't work as it get the distinct users of each day without taking into consideration the users of the previous day